# SQL: Select rows if it fuzzy matches with corresponding column

Tags: sql, select, presto, case-when

I have a data frame which has 2 columns

```
**Job**    **Station**
Service      ServiceA
Wash         ServiceA
Service      WashA
Service      ServiceA
Wash         WashA
Wash         WashB 
Wash         Invoice
Wash         Entry
Service      Invoice
Service      Entry
```

Job takes values Service or Wash whereas Station takes values ServiceA, ServiceB, WashA, WAshB. There are entries corresponding to Job 'Service' as 'WashA' which is incorrect as Service should correspond to only ServiceA or ServiceB. Entry and Invoice should stay for every job. I want to select the rows which are only correctly mapped.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where station like concat(job, '%')
```

This checks that the leading characters in `station` match `job`.

Comment: You are right, but I just edited the question a little. Could you help with that too?

Comment: select t.*
from t
where station in (concat(job, '%'), 'Entry', 'Invoice') .   This doesn't work. It selects only Entry and Invoice